# MS Teams: can't receive a date/time from adaptive card in the ru-RU locale

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

Tested on the web-version and the latest desktop version. 
In the en-US locale all works fine.
Below is example of a Date input.

```
{
    "type": "Column",
    "width": "stretch",
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "Input.Date",
            "id": "StartDate",
            "min": "29.10.19"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "Input.Text",
    "id": "Text"
},
```

Result: after the user has sent the card, bot framework receives a json with the all input values except the date / time inputs:

```
{
  "Text":"111",
  // no field with "StartDate" name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. This is a known issue with Adaptive Card. We have a bug on this and we are working on fixing this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a MS bug report...